# Dynamically rendering member data into a single page layout on next.js

Tags: next.js, app-router

I am using latest Next.js App router.

I have two .ts files, one that holds an interface for my member data field types, and a second that holds the specific data values.

I import these onto my home page to render the correct images/names..etc... This works perfectly.

I then have folders/files inside my app folder as follows: app/family/[memberId].tsx

The memberId.tsx file holds the page that I want the data rendered into dependent on which member is clicked on.

Currently I am mapping each member into a slider using the familyMemberData that I have imported.

What I want to know is - What is the best way/conventions to dynamically render specific data per family member but using the same page layout? So when I click on Dave for example, the same page is loaded as when I click James, but only the data for the specific member is rendered.